# Simple form not submitting to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, simple-form

I'm building a simple online shop for practice and want to track order histories, at the moment I'm getting the user to submit but the shipping address and order history, later I'll upgrade order history to be a hidden field.

The problem is that I can't get the simple form to submit anything to my database.

My form looks like this:

```
<p class="text-center">
    congratulations your order is almost complete, please fill out the form below to place your order or <%= link_to "browse other products.", root_path %>
  </p>



<%= simple_form_for @placeorder, html: {  multipart: true }  do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs" >
  <%= f.input :shipping_address, label: false, placeholder: 'Shipping address', input_html: { class: 'input-lg', required: true } %> 
   <%= f.input :order_history, label: false, placeholder: 'order_history', input_html: { class: 'input-lg', required: true } %> 
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Confirm order" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My place order controller looks like this:

```
class PlaceOrdersController < ApplicationController


  def new
    current_order.order_items.each do |order_item|
     @last_item_name = order_item.product.name
    end
    @placeorder = PlaceOrder.new
    @order = current_order.order_items
  end

  def create
    @placeorder = PlaceOrder.create(place_order_params)
    p  "HELLO #{@placeorder}"
    if @placeorder.save
      flash[:success] = "You've made your order"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong, check the form and submit your order again"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

   def place_order_params
    params.require(:place_order).permit(:shipping_address, :order_history)
  end

end
```

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
  resources :checkout
  resources :place_orders
  resource :cart, only: [:show]
  resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy], defaults: { format: 'js' }
  root to: "products#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
end
```

I have other forms that are working fine and they look the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to take some debugging steps to actually pinpoint the problem for anybody to be able to help you. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: You are using `create` inside the create method. Use `@placeorder = PlaceOrder.new(place_order_params)` instead.

Comment: What error do you get in your log? Do you get redirected back to your new action when trying to save? @Emu i think is right though. Check out this doc, it has a basic create action example. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller        .create() instantiates and tries to save. .new() only instantiates and needs .save() to save the object.

Comment: @RichardWatkins actual create should still work in your controller, but save isnt really needed then.  Are you passing your validations in your model or DB? That would prevent a save.

Comment: after `@placeorder.save` puts `@placeorder.errors` but I highly recommend do you learn about `binding.pry` or `better_errors gem`